# How to show branch coverage in Intellij?

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, test-coverage

I'm wondering how I could configure IntelliJ to show the branch coverage along with code Class, Method and Line coverage. I know that changing Sampling to Tracing in the Edit Configurations would enable highlight for that in the code, but I want to see the actual percentage as well. Please help. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Branch coverage is available only in Tracing mode.

Comment: I have selected tracing mode. It indeed shows branches hits in the code level but it does not show the overall percentage as it does for the line coverage.